# Is it good practice to have multiple accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Being on this site for a while I am becoming suspicious of users having multiple accounts. I have no proof but it seems some conversations in comments go a little too smoothly. I wonder if this is a good practice for such a site? And if it doesn’t give special privileges where there shouldn't be, and at the same time prioritize the direction of questions and conversations allowed.

I appreciate any tags this would require.

Comment: If you think there is an illegitimate use of sockpuppets, feel free to flag posts of them so we can have a reasonability check using the means available.

Answer (score 4):

This has been asked on Meta.SE. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange).

Based on those answers: the policy is that it's okay as long as such users don't abuse their multiple accounts. To quote from one of the answers:

> **If the second account allows you to do something on the site that your
>   normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse**. Examples of
>   this include (*but are not limited to*):
>
> - Voting on your own posts or comments
> - Answering your own questions with the other account(s)
> - Casting multiple votes on others' posts or comments
> - Supporting your own arguments (*"+1: shog is right, don't know why the rest of you don't realize this"*)
> - Using bounties to circumvent the rep cap
> - Circumventing suspensions, quality bans, or the rate limits on posting questions / answers / comments / etc.